# How to access forms of ng-included html's from the parent html?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have step1.html which will be included in a parent.html as follows

```
   <body>
        <button ng-click='go(childForm)' value='Click'>
        <div ng-include="'step1.html'"></div>
   </body>
```

step1.html ,

```
<form name='childForm'>
     ...
</form>
```

inside **`go`** function, I am always getting **`undefined`** as the input parameter. I can understand that the parent html is rendered before the `step1.html` is included, so the value will be undefined. Is there any way to send the child form to the parent scope method?

Comment: cn't put the button inside the `step1.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-include` creates a child scope so your form name is only being set on that child scope

To fix it, make the form name an object property and define that object in the parent controller

```
$scope.model={};    

<form name='model.childForm'>
```

Now the `model` object exists in the ng-include child scope and `ng-form` will add the new `childForm` property  to it